# Linked Server with MS SQL crashing / stopping after 5 sec

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server-2005

Hey, I have been having a problem with my linked servers.  I am using Microsoft Server 2003 and Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2005. I am linking to a MYSQL database through Microsoft studio since all of our other databases are controlled through MSMS.

The problem is that for any query that last for more than 5 sec I get this error:

**[Msg 0, Level 11, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Msg 0, Level 20, State 0, Line 0
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.]**

Any other query under 5 sec works fine.  I am doing simple [select * from tables].  I have checked all the time-outs etc and have them set at unlimited.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer which was actually answered on the "serverfault" forum:

https://serverfault.com/questions/116035/sql-server-severe-error-when-querying-a-mysql-linked-server/116052#116052